# Hive Date functions not properly handling the dates

Tags: hive, sql-date-functions

I have a daily job that handles the loads based on the date I derive using hive date functions. It was running fine until 2 days ago and the issue started from 12/30/2019. It is showing the year as 2020 when I use the date_format else it shows 2019. See below.

```
hive> select current_date;
OK
2019-12-31
Time taken: 0.182 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select date_format(current_date,'dd-MMM-YYYY');
OK
31-Dec-2020
Time taken: 0.429 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

hive> select cast(date_format(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,1),'YYYYMMdd') AS string);
OK
20201230
```

Did anyone else face this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got into a classic mistake people do.

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year
>   whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO
>   year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same
>   number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the
>   calendar year.

Change your code as below (lower case yyyy) to get correct results:

```
hive> select date_format(current_date,'dd-MMM-yyyy');
OK
31-Dec-2019

select cast(date_format(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE,1),'yyyyMMdd') AS string);
OK
20191230
```

Make sure you change CURRENT_DATE to '2019-12-31' for testing purposes.